# не могу исправить found 1 high severity vulnerability

Tags: linux, npm

Выполняю `npm install` в папке проекта. Появляется сообщение "found 1 high severity vulnerability". `npm audit fix` и `npm audit fix --force` не помогают. Аудит показывает соответственно вот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при выполнении `npm audit fix`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ни установка новой версии csv, ни обновления - ничего не помогает
Что делать?

Comment: Добавьте вывод ошибок из `npm audit fix`

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой проблемой при установке sqlite3. Решил её через установку пакета по ссылке с gitHub.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так: npm audit fix
По идее должен подтянуть фиксы если есть они вообще.

Comment: ТС уже написал: `npm audit fix ... не помогают`